# QProgressDialog: How to adjust the width to show the whole progress bar?

Tags: qt, qprogressbar

I create a `QProgressDialog`, set a `QProgressBar` to it. Set the format

"Processing section %v of %m. Percentage completed: %p."

to the `QProgressBar`. But the text is cut, not the whole progress bar is displayed on the dialog.

[image]

How to adjust the width to show the whole progress bar?

Comment: Set a fixed width may solve this problem, but I don't want to hardcode the width.

Comment: may be, set minimum width rather than fixed width?

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example which uses `QFontMetrics` to get the width of the progress bar's text, and then adds 100px to this for the progress bar itself. When the dialog is shown, it is resized to this width.

```
auto dialog = new QProgressDialog();
dialog->setWindowTitle("Progress");
dialog->setLabelText("Test progress dialog");

auto bar = new QProgressBar(dialog);
bar->setTextVisible(true);
bar->setValue(50);
bar->setFormat("Processing section %v of %m. Percentage completed: %p");
dialog->setBar(bar);

// Use QFontMetrics to get the width of the bar text,
// and then add 100px for the progress bar itself. Set
// this to the initial dialog width.
int width = QFontMetrics(bar->font()).width(bar->text()) + 100;
dialog->resize(width, dialog->height());
dialog->show();
```

This allows you to avoid hardcoding a width, although it's a bit complicated. I think just setting a reasonable minimum width like below is probably a better/simpler solution:

```
dialog->setMinimumWidth(300);
```

Comment: Thanks @ajshort, That would be a workaround. Why not the QProgressDialog auto-fit the width?